# GWT - GXT - GAE. Reporting in PDF

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, pdf, gxt

I'm developing a app in Google app Engine with GWT and GXT so i don't know how create a PDF report. I am new in GAE and i understand that JasperReports, BIRT, iText, etc don't run in GAE for white-list. What Framework or lib can i to use?. I am using RPC Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bruno Lowagie from iText recently mentioned a GAE compatible port of iText: http://www.parleys.com/#id=3147&st=5

I haven't looked into it, but maybe this could be interesting for you.

Comment: Thx for quickly answer. Yes!!!, he said that iText for android can be used in GAE...

Comment: thx for answer.The last version iText is compatible with GAE.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Conversion API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/conversion/). It's not a full reporting engine, but if you can create html, with the help of some templating engine ([Mustache](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) is tested to work on GAE), then the Conversion API can convert it to PDF.

Comment: Thx for quickly answer. I'm going to look.

Answer (score 0):

There is an online-service called [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) which you can call from GAE to generate documents based on templates which you upload separately.  Upside is trivial coding effort to get decent documents and there are Java examples.  Downside is that it's not free.